# calling method repeatedly after 3 seconds time interval in background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsthread

I have gone through many sites but still no answer.

I have a **method** suppose `void xyz()`, **which will get called automatically** from a **View Controller**  after **every 3 seconds**.

I have no idea what to use, do I have to use **NSThread** or **PerformSelector.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call this method from ViewDidLoad method.ViewDidLoad will when your view will be appear in iPhone device or Simulator.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self selector:@selector(runMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


    -(void)runMethod

    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
-(void)xyz{
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(xyz) withObject:nil];
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad  {
   [self performSelector:@selector(xyz) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSTimer`

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self selector:@selector(xyz) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use NSTimer as mentioned by @mokujin.
Please visit https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html